# Strict matching of strings and integers

Tags: mysql

I am writing a flexible search mechanism for a customer's website. I am utilizing union clauses to query a number of different fields in the database in search of a string value entered by the user. This works fine except for one issue.

When comparing a string of a text to an integer that is currently set to zero, the match always returns true. In other words, according to MySQL, "email@example.com" is equal to 0.

I have tried utilizing the CAST and CONVERT function to turn this into a standard string to string comparison, but I can't seem to get the syntax right. My attempts either repeat the above issue or return no rows at all when some should match. I am also concerned that doing this would have an effect on performance since I am combining lots of unions.

What I really need is a strict comparison between an entered string and the value in the database, be it an integer or string.

EDIT:
Here is an example.

```
CREATE  TABLE `test_table` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
`phone` BIGINT(19) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = MyISAM;

INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `email`, `phone`) VALUES (1, 'email@example.com', 0);

SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE phone = 'email@example.com';
```

Execute this and the one row that has been inserted will return. My issue is that it shouldn't!

Comment: We can't tell you what you did wrong if you don't show your code. Normally you specify the data type to use when calling `prepare()` (assuming you're using prepared statements, as you should to avoid SQL injection).

Comment: I have edited the post to provide an example. I am handling SQL injection and other security measures before the string reaches the query.

Comment: Where in your example are you comparing a string with an integer?

Comment: WHERE phone = 'email@example.com';
The phone field is an integer. It is being compared against a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should fail:

```
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE cast(phone as char) = 'email@example.com';
```

The cause of the original problem is that when comparing strings and numbers, it converts the string to a number (so you can write `where phone = '123'`). You need to use an explicit cast of the field to make it a string-to-string comparison, to prevent this default conversion.

Unfortunately, casting like this is likely to prevent it from using indexes. Even if the field is already `char`, the cast apparently prevents it from indexing.

You could also solve it during input validation: if `phone` is an integer, don't allow the user to provide a non-integer value in the search field.

Comment: You repeat some of the concerns I express in my original post above concerning performance. The use of indexes was exactly what I was implying. I am amused that you suggest the very same solution I attempted to utilize -- the CAST function. In either case, you gave me a working example of the syntax and that appears to work for me. My initial tests are not showing me any immediate performance issues with the number of records I'm working with, so I may be ok for now. Thanks.

Comment: I tried it on a table with 2.5M rows, the query took 7 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

How about replacing:

```
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE phone = 'email@example.com'
```

with:

```
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE phone = 'email@example.com' and phone <> 0
```

<> means different from.

This will work for you because you are using 0 in the phone column to mean there isn't a phone number (although it would be better style to use NULL for no phone number).

Comment: That won't necessarily work. If `phone` is 1, `WHERE phone = '1email@example.com` will be true.