# How to make MySQL strict on types

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Here's the scenario, we are building a web application in Laravel, and assigned a route as follows:

```
Route::get('/sample/{client}', 'SampleController@SampleMethod')->name('SampleNaming');
```

The method SampleMethod, reads from the client variable and displays data about the client in the page.

if we go to http://localhost/appurl/sample/1 for example, it displays data about client id 1. The trick is that if we go to http://localhost/appurl/sample/1abc , it will still display the data for client id 1.

Tried the query in MySQL,

```
select * from clients where ID = '1abc'
```

The ID column is an integer and the primary key of the clients table.

The above query gave me the result for Client ID 1, turns out that MySQL checks the provided string and searches for the integer part in it and fetches the rows accordingly.

Surely, we can escape this in PHP / Laravel however my question is, is there a way to make MySQL strict on such scenarios?

Comment: This [could be a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654137/strict-matching-of-strings-and-integers)

Comment: It's actually different, I read this one before.. not the same issue we're facing, my question is how we can make the mysql innodb strict on types

Comment: what is the type for the ID field in mysql?

Comment: Integer, it's the primary key, shouldn't it throw error in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure Laravel solution is to use [Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints).

```
Route::get('/sample/{client}', 'SampleController@SampleMethod')
    ->name('SampleNaming')
    ->where(['client' => '[0-9]+']);
```

Comment: True, After all it seems that the best way is to restrict type usage in Laravel. Even MySQL strict mode wouldn't fix it. Thanks.

Comment: @nitrex Well its always a string you are getting from request, you are just restricting what chars are allowed, I think you know that; just making sure. BTW: I must say intriguing question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to change sql_mode setting for your server. you need to use strict mode.
[enter link description here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html)

Comment: Tried this earlier, even with InnoDB strict mode variable as ON, still have the same result. Could be that MySQL is built that way... Interesting to know.

Answer (score 0):

preventing type casting is not configurable in mysql. [mysql implicit type casting rules](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html)

you can use the cast function to solve the issue at the sql level

```
select * from t where cast(id as char) = "1abcd"
```