# Why MySQL automatically converts strings to numbers?

Tags: mysql

When I try compare this `65 = '65ae3ee2-aeb2-427f-8381-56db91b94363'` mysql returns `true`, why?

```
SELECT query * FROM families
WHERE id = '65ae3ee2-aeb2-427f-8381-56db91b94363'
OR fam_code = '65ae3ee2-aeb2-427f-8381-56db91b94363'
```

returns two records:

```
id fam_code

65 c648b66e-ae0c-467b-af56-1e6d3c214f2e

92 65ae3ee2-aeb2-427f-8381-56db91b94363
```

Why is that?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654137/strict-matching-of-strings-and-integers

Comment: Thank you  @T.J. Crowder you answer is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It returns these two records, why is that?

Because that's how MySQL tries to cast strings to numbers (to check against your integer id). Basically, it reads as much number as it can, and throws the rest away.

```
65ae3ee2-aeb2-427f-8381-56db91b94363
^^ 
Can interpret this as a number.

65ae3ee2-aeb2-427f-8381-56db91b94363
  ^ 
  Garbage starts. Ignore this and the rest of the string.
```

Comment: thanks for answer but how can i fix it?

Comment: By not using that SQL? What fix do you WANT? More a business decision.

Comment: How to cast string to numbers? how check equality of string and number?

Comment: @LosPollosHermanos: what do you mean, "how to cast string to numbers"? That's what you get here for free, without doing anything.

Comment: @LosPollosHermanos: you may find TJCrowder's comment useful.

Answer (score 3):

In order to compare numbers with strings, MySQL converts both values to real numbers (stored used the floating-point standard).

The rules are described in the ["Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) documentation page:

> The following rules describe how conversion occurs for comparison operations:
>
> - If one or both arguments are `NULL`, the result of the comparison is `NULL`, except for the `NULL`-safe `<=>` equality comparison operator. For `NULL <=> NULL`, the result is `true`. No conversion is needed.
> - If both arguments in a comparison operation are strings, they are compared as strings.
> - If both arguments are integers, they are compared as integers.
> - Hexadecimal values are treated as binary strings if not compared to a number.
> - If one of the arguments is a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` column and the other argument is a constant, the constant is converted to a timestamp before the comparison is performed. [...]
> - If one of the arguments is a decimal value, comparison depends on the other argument. The arguments are compared as decimal values if the other argument is a decimal or integer value, or as floating-point values if the other argument is a floating-point value.
> - In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers.

The case you described fits into the last item: *"in all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers"*.

Comment: Thank @axiac for you extended answer!